# Old Raid pops up and destroys everything

Tags: raid, ubuntu-12.04, software-raid

I have a root server with a mdadm two-disk raid 0 on Ubuntu. One HDD failed and I continued to work on the second. The server hoster somehow repaired the defect HDD and after a server restart it was reintegrated into the raid.

Sadly, I can only access the old files! The new state of the raid got overwritten by the old HDD. Is there some way to rescue the new files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Rememeber, RAID is not backup, it's redundancy. With Ubuntu (and other *nix File Systems), removing the file removes the inode to the file. The data may physically be there, but you'd need to go in and find the start/end of each file, assign it a file name, hope it's the right version of the file, etc.

Comment: So basically, I'm f*cked.

Comment: The data is *not* physically there. When the RAID array was rebuilt, it was returned to the state it was in when the drive left the array. Any changes after that are totally lost, since the array has been rebuilt. (Assuming the OP meant 2-disk RAID 0.)

Comment: @silvinci I'm afraid so....